# Access VBA: Unable to add new column without Error 3211

Tags: vba, ms-access, runtime-error

I'm trying to add a new column/field using VBA into my newly created table and newly created database, i.e. there is absolutely nothing in the table or database. My code is as follows:

```
Sub test()
    CurrentDb.Execute ("ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD COLUMN Column2 Text;")
End Sub
```

However, this results in the following error message:

```
Run-time error '3211':

The database engine could not lock table 'Table1' because it is already in use by another person or process.
```

I'm the only user accessing the table. Running other snippets of VBA code works fine, but this particular piece of code throws this error.

I've tried deleting the database and creating a new one; shutting down all instances of Access; and restarting my computer, but this error still occurs.

Comment: Try compact and repair? Do you have any windows other than the main access window open? Are there any startup macros that might open a hidden window? What happens if you add the column using the Table Designer?

Comment: @ZevSpitz Don't think compact and repair would make a difference here since I'm happy to just delete the database and create a completely new one from scratch to test out this code snippet. The only open windows are the main Access window and the in-built VBA IDE. Adding a column using the UI works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error will be raised if you have the table open.

So, before calling your function, make sure table1 is closed.